# Creating a search endpoint in Mongo and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, api-design

I've been teaching myself basically a MERN CRUD project but haven't done anything on the front end as of yet. I have been able to get the API working properly on all the basic crud functionality. The thing I've been struggling with is constructing an endpoint that allows someone to search the MongoDB and return any matches.

I've been trying to pass a key that would be part of the HTTP GET request and use that with the Mongoose find function, but am not getting anywhere.  I'll show what my working "findById" function looks like:

```
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
  App.findById(req.params.noteId)
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          note: "Note not found with id " + req.params.noteId,
        });
      }
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.kind === "ObjectId") {
        return res.status(404).send({
          note: "Note not found with id " + req.params.noteId,
        });
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
        note: "Error retrieving note with id " + req.params.noteId,
      });
    });
};
```

So I tried to model the search function based off of that:

```
exports.search = async (req, res) => {
  App.find(req.params.key)
  .then((data) => {
    if (!data) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        note: "Note not found with search query: " + req.params.key,
      });
    }
    res.send(data);
  })}
```

The error I'm getting is "Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object"
Any ideas appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: What is the issue with when you use findById?

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. const castError = new CastError(); is the error I'm technically getting when I try to use findById in my search function. But I already can successfully find any record by ID that you can see in the first function. I'm trying to search the "value" part of the {key: value} pairs and return those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "The 'filter' parameter to find() must be an object" indicates that you are passing an invalid value to the find method. In this case, you are passing req.params.key as a parameter, but the find method expects to receive a filter object as a parameter.

To fix this error, just pass a valid filter object to the find method. For example, if you want to search for all documents that have the field "name" with the value "John", the code would be:

Comment: exports.search = (req, res) => {
   const filter = { name: "John" }; // filter to search for all documents named "John"

   App.find(filter)
     .then((date) => {
       if (!data) {
         return res.status(404).send({
           note: "No documents found with this query",
         });
       }
       res.send(data);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       return res.status(500).send({
         note: "Error when trying to perform the query",
       });
     });
};

Comment: Remember that the filter object can be any object valid for the MongoDB query. You can find more information about the query operators available in MongoDB here.

I hope this helps! If you have more questions or need more help, just ask.

Comment: Many thanks, your answer led to me down the rabbit hole and finding an answer using
{note:{$regex:req.params.key}} for my search which works perfectly.